# Automaticly and seamlessly sync iPhone photos as soon as they're taken (over the air)

Tags: data-synchronization, ios, iphone, photos, network

I use [Snappy](http://snappy.kb1ooo.com/). That's my preferred photo app of all! So, please, keep this in mind.

Ideally I want to be able to sync to picasa *and* dropbox. But I wouldn't mind if it was flickr, picposterous or whatever, as long as it's really automatic and seamless, unlike [this guy's solution](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1943/with-an-iphone-is-there-a-way-to-automatically-sync-photos-taken-with-the-camera). I've tried many apps and couldn't find a single one (apparently unlike [this guy](https://www.dropbox.com/votebox/4329/automatic-sync-of-entire-iphone-photos), which is the reason why I started this question).

Dropbox app like few others do let you take photos from inside the app and submit the photo. But that's not even a seamless sync - if there's no internet connection the photo won't be sent as soon as internet becomes available unless the app stays open.

Maybe a good solution would be just an app able to monitor the DCIM folder and send any new ones through e-mail as soon as it sees it. Then we could use pixelpipe, instapaper, sendtodropbox or anything! That way the iOS already handles sending e-mails exactly the way we expect - *it will go through as soon as a connection is available*.

For now, I'm using [Picbox](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/picbox-upload-your-camera/id400746312?mt=8) - it softens the whole manual process at least... But that's still not it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like telepathy [has been proven](http://www.apple.com/ios/ios5/features.html#camera) since for sure nobody from apple read my "suggestion" here!

Answer (score 1):

I too have tried to find something to do this, with little success. Documenting what people have tried may be helpful, so here's my list:

- [Cinq](http://blog.davinciware.com/p/dropphox_18.html) -- offers to sync with iPhoto on the Mac, or to the filesystem on a Mac or PC; only works for photos taken within Cinq
- [DropPhox](http://blog.davinciware.com/p/dropphox_18.html) -- syncs with Dropbox; only works for photos taken within DropPhox
- [Eye-Fi](http://www.eye.fi/blog/eye-fi-view-email-sharing-ipad-sweepstakes-and-more) -- syncs to local machine, and lots of online services (Picasa and Flickr but not Dropbox); free (although nags to upgrade); will sync photos that were taken with any camera app on the iPhone; requires (as far as i can see) an Eye-Fi card to set up an account and get it working

All of these have their drawbacks; would love to find the app that can upload all photos automatically.

Comment: I actually bought Eye-fi little more than 1 year ago and I don't know where it is and never used it! But I doubt even that would be able to sync as I described. I was hoping for a jailbroken solution. But thanks for giving a shot and reminding me of eye.fi!

Comment: You don't need to use the Eye-Fi card, all you need to do is register and then download the iPhone app. This app is the most promising of the lot for me.

Comment: I couldn't find the eyefi card and I don't think they allow anyone to register - just customers who have the card. I'm in contact with the support, but their answer isn't being much encouraging given I may have lost the card.

Comment: For now I'm using [Picbox](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/picbox-upload-your-camera/id400746312?mt=8), but that's still not it...

Comment: Interesting, thanks, I'll take a look, seems like an improvement on DropPhox