# How can I get photographs off the iPhone 4 wirelessly?

Tags: iphone

My new iPhone 4 takes pretty good pictures (for a phone); they're comparable to a lower-end point and shoot. Very convenient.

But it's a pain in the butt to get the pictures off the phone. I have to manually plug it into the computer and import somehow (I use Windows Live Photo Gallery). It works, but it's cumbersome.

Is there a way to get a whole bunch of photographs off the device wirelessly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your iPhone 4 supports iOS 5.0, which can now sync photos wirelessly using [Photo Stream](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH2596?viewlocale=en_US).

For setup instructions, see http://support.apple.com/kb/PH2605

Answer (score 6):

Eye-Fi has an iPhone app that will perform essentially the same function as the Eye-Fi SD Cards (wirelessly transfer photos to your computer and/or the web).  More information can be [found on their website](http://www.eye.fi/products/iphone) - the catch is that you need to have an Eye-Fi card.  No, it doesn't appear to actually use the card, but they give the app away to card owners.

Comment: I do actually have an Eye-Fi card. Looks like this app will do the trick -- that is, when it is updated to work with iOS4. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Eye-Fi app will work for this, and works fine with iOS4. Possible duplicate of http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/10733/automaticly-and-seamlessly-sync-iphone-photos-as-soon-as-theyre-taken-over-the/

Answer (score 1):

I use [PhotoSync](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/photosync-wirelessly-transfers/id415850124?mt=8) to transfer pictures wirelessly from iPhone <-> iPad, and from iOS devices <-> computer. They have little computer utilities on their [website](http://www.photosync-app.com/photosync/en/downloads.html) to send and catch the photos on a PC or Mac. It handles bulk transfers too. I've had good luck with it so far.

Answer (score 0):

[DropBox](http://www.dropbox.com/)

The iPhone app lets you upload photos and videos. You can them sync them from DropBox to your computer when you get home. The only downside is that you have to select each photo in your Camera Roll at a time. Can't do mass uploads from the iPhone.

Comment: I think the OP is looking for a bulk upload.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go got [DropBox](http://www.dropbox.com/), although it is true that you used to have to upload images one by one the latest version now has bulk upload. When you choose upload it shows you your camera role, you tick which photos you would like to upload, tap go and it uploads them all.

I have matched this with [Hazel](http://www.noodlesoft.com/hazel.php) on my laptop for it to watch my DropBox folder and any Photos taken on my iPhone that appear in DropBox are then moved to my desktop (or other folder). Although the same action can be performed with out hazel but with a little knowledge of AppleScript.