# What's a good Picasa upload app for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, software-recommendation, photos, picasa

Android has "Instant Upload" with the Google+ app. I'd like something similar for iPhone: **an app that takes all my photos and uploads them to a private album on Picasa Web Albums.** Jailbreak alternatives are fine too.

Searching the App Store for the word "picasa" gives me far too many results. There are some Picasa album-browsing apps, and a few uploading tools (mostly paid; free versions only upload thumbnails). Rather than testing out all 59+ apps myself, perhaps some fellow users here have personal experiences and recommendations?

I'm using Linux on my pc. This means that iTunes is not an option. (Yes, it's a hassle...) I am looking for something that can **upload straight from iPhone to web, without [requiring a computer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1943/with-an-iphone-is-there-a-way-to-automatically-sync-photos-taken-with-the-camer/1944#1944)** as a middle step.

Bonus points for operation in the background, but I'll accept an app that requires to be foreground -- as long as it can upload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the new answer is the Google+ app for iOS.

Comment: Times change, apps improve. Google+ for iOS is the tool of choice (even though it only allows 2048x2048 resolution).

Answer (score 2):

I use [Web Albums](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/web-albums-a-picasa-photo/id344997890) and it works well. It's currently $2.99 on the US store.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the relevent website, or iTunes App Store link?

Comment: http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/web-albums-a-picasa-photo/id344997890 for $2.99

Comment: Thanks -- I found that the same author also has another app called "[Up](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/up-a-picasa-photo-video-uploader/id399922612)" for $0.99 -- I wonder if Web Albums is 3x better or not.

Comment: This app is crazy. You need to have location services enabled for bulk upload? Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

**Photoforge2** is an excellent photo editing app for both iPhone and iPad that uploads to Picasa and just about everything else. It's a real bargain too: [£0.69 in the UK](http://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/photoforge2/id435789422?mt=8)/[$0.99 in the US](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/photoforge2/id435789422?mt=8).

There are plenty of other options too: see my [round up of iPad photo apps](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2442/what-is-the-best-photographic-editing-tool-for-ipad/15465#15465) over on photo.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Looking at the iTunes page, it appears that the app can't do bulk upload, but only the one pic it's currently editing?

Comment: Yes, I think that's the case. Sorry, missed that you specifically wanted bulk uploads.

Answer (score 0):

I used [PhotoSync](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/photosync-wirelessly-transfers/id415850124?mt=8) (US$1.99) and was impressed by its features. You can not only upload to Picasa but also Flickr, Dropbox and other services, including to your computer or another iphone/iPad.